# Validate MSSQL identifier (parameter) in .NET or regular expression

Tags: .net, sql-server, regex, t-sql

In a .NET project I need to verify if a string is a valid Microsoft SQL Server 2005 parameter identifier.

*Example:* `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = @parameter`

**Is there a runtime class method to validate a string for being a parameter, or is there a regular expression that verifies the rules?** (see below)

[From the documentation on identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874(SQL.90).aspx), parameters should comply to these general identifier rules:

> 1. The first character must be one of the following:   * A letter as defined
>      by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The
>      Unicode definition of letters includes
>      Latin characters from a through z,
>      from A through Z, and also letter
>      characters from other languages.  *
>      The underscore (_), at sign (@), or
>      number sign (#).
>     Certain symbols
>      at the beginning of an identifier have
>      special meaning in SQL Server. A
>      regular identifier that starts with
>      the at sign always denotes a local
>      variable or parameter and cannot be
>      used as the name of any other type of
>      object. An identifier that starts with
>      a number sign denotes a temporary
>      table or procedure. An identifier that
>      starts with double number signs (##)
>      denotes a global temporary object.
>      Although the number sign or double
>      number sign characters can be used to
>      begin the names of other types of
>      objects, we do not recommend this
>      practice. Some Transact-SQL functions
>      have names that start with double at
>      signs (@@). To avoid confusion with
>      these functions, you should not use
>      names that start with @@.
> 2. Subsequent characters can include the following:   * Letters as defined
>      in the Unicode Standard 3.2.  *
>      Decimal numbers from either Basic
>      Latin or other national scripts.  *
>      The at sign, dollar sign ($), number
>      sign, or underscore.
> 3. The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. SQL Server
>      reserves both the uppercase and
>      lowercase versions of reserved words.
> 4. Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.
> 5. Supplementary characters are not allowed.
>
> When identifiers are used in
>   Transact-SQL statements, the
>   identifiers that do not comply with
>   these rules must be delimited by
>   double quotation marks or brackets.

Since I want to validate parameters only, identifiers must start with an @ sign, and must not be delimited.

Comment: Are you trying to parse SQL from some app, or do you want to run the SQL statement afterwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was stumbling over the Unicode character classes, but once I found out that they are supported in .NET regular expressions, I came up with the following regular expression solving my question:

`@[\p{L}{\p{Nd}}$#_][\p{L}{\p{Nd}}@$#_]*`

This enforces:

- Identifier always starts with @, making it a parameter.
- No @ in the second position allowed to avoid confusion with special TSQL functions.
- Allows only characters as defined in the rules.

Comment: +1, but I would like to point out that `@@identifiers` are not supported by this regular expression. @BartVerkoeijen pointed out his reasoning, but it should be clear that even while they might be confused for special TSQL functions, they are in fact valid identifiers. A regular expression that exactly fits the specification would be `@[\p{L}\p{Nd}@$#_]+`

Comment: @LunicLynx This will allow multiple `@`s anywhere in the identifier. If that's intentional, then perfect :-) If you want to allow either one or two `@` symbols at the start only, then consider starting the regex with `@@?` instead of including `@` in the character class.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article about creating a function for evaluating regular expressions on TSQL, internally uses VBScript, check it out [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/)

Another link you can find useful, but i think it needs registration, [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/sql2000dbatoolkitpart2/2362/)

Another idea could be handle @parameter as a sysname datatype, don't know if it fits here

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'd like to check the rules on the client side (in this case ASP.NET) and not on the server side. I'm sorry if I was unclear on this part.